# Publish Outlook Add-in mobile on the Microsoft AppSource marketplace

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-app, office-js-store

I have a desktop/web add-in for outlook that is already published on the Microsoft AppSource marketplace.

I updated the manifest to have support for the mobile version. The manifest was verified by microsoft.
Now, when I manually add the manifest as a Custom Add-in I can see the mobile add-in on my phone. But, when I'm using the add-in directly from the marketplace, I can't see the mobile add-in. Even though the manifest got verified.

What step am I missing?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the latest version is listed in the `AppSource`. On the details page you can find the add-in version, for example, see https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104381712?exp=ubp8&tab=DetailsAndSupport .

If the right version is listed then I'd suggest clearing the add-ins cache on the device (or browser cache). See [Clear the Office cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache) for more information.

To verify the problem I'd suggest installing the web add-in on a new device.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Eugene.
@ RoyBenAviv Please let us know if issue still persists after following the given steps.

Comment: Hey, I updated the version with the mobile support and now it is showing the right version on the microsoft store. I still can't see the mobile version when using the live version, but it is showing when I manually add the manifest.

What can be the cause now?
Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest posting new questions in new threads so readers could recognize questions and answers easily.